# Hermit living down a well. How deep can he safely go?

Tags: science-based, physics, survival

A holy man lives down a cylindrical well that is 2 metres in diameter. There is no water in the bottom and all the walls are of solid impermeable rock. He is protected from rain by a roof on supports.

He is kept alive by the locals who believe his prayers are necessary for their well-being. They assiduously lower food and water and haul up waste products at regular intervals.

**Question**

How deep can the well be before his exhalations are sufficient to suffocate him?

**Assumptions**

There are no toxic gases leaking into the well.

There is no active ventilation to the tunnel. In order to breathe the hermit must rely on diffusion. (or convection - see below)

The well is on the equator so the Sun is directly overhead once per 24 hours. The resulting temperature changes throughout the day and night will presumably cause an exchange of air by convection. (or will they?)

Comment: The US Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA) considers any digging [deeper than five feet](https://www.osha.gov/FedReg_osha_pdf/FED20150504.pdf) to be a confined space requiring risk mitigation. The horrifying accident stories that led to the rule begin on Page 105.

Comment: You can create a natural ventilation if you divide the well with a vertical carpet into two halfs, leaving a gap at the bottom. This trick is used to get dust out of boreholes. The air will go down on one side and get up on the other side.

Comment: Just a minute. If there's a roof over the well, how can the Sun cause temperature changes down the hole!?

Comment: Obligatory xkcd:  https://what-if.xkcd.com/135/

Comment: On a side note I don't see the reason for the close votes...could the previous close voters comment?

Comment: @elemtilas - It's a Plexiglas roof!  However, even if it wasn't the roof is supported on poles so air can move through.

Answer (score 4):

Wells have been hand dug to a depth of 390 metres, so considerably deeper than this especially if the person was not exerting themselves. Gases are very good a defusing especially if containers are being hauled up and down the well shaft, so probably a lot deeper indeed.

The ultimate depth would probably be more restricted by temperature increase than by gas diffusion. At 4000 metres I am confident that the person would not survive due to excessive temperature and probably would not survive at considerably shallower depths for the same reason.

So a best estimate would be 1000 – 2500 metres

[Deepest hole dug by hand](https://www.bbc.com/future/story/20150327-the-deepest-holes-dug-by-hand)

Answer (score 4):

### I doubt gas exchange would be the limiting factor.

The deeper the hole, the longer it takes to exchange the gas, true. But it also increases the size of your oxygen tank. And in terms of CO2 buildup, think about how fast a fart can spread through a room. Your hermit isn't breathing fast enough to decrease the concentration of oxygen to harmful levels, because there's so much oxygen in the well.

What I would expect to be the causes of danger (in order of the depth needed for them to occur, shallowest to deepest):

1. **10+ meters – Things falling in:** A rock falling down a deep well would be enough to kill the guy when it gets to the bottom. You could have barriers to prevent this, but they'd have to be careful lowering things down. If the rope breaks, he might get killed by a falling water jug. So they don't drop anything. In that case,
2. **50+ meters – Collapses:** At some point, it gets really hard to stop the well from caving in on itself. The bigger the hole, the more rock that has to be kept from falling in from the walls. Suppose the well is reinforced with indestructible walls. Then:
3. **600+ meters – Temperature:** The earth gets really hot down there. It doesn't really matter how much food and water you have if you live in an oven. Assume the indestructible walls are also perfect insulators:
4. **??+ meters – Gas exchange:** I'm not sure when this would start, but it would be very far down. I'm also not positive that diffusion would ever be slower than the ascetic's rate of gas exchange through breathing. Also, as you mentioned, there would likely be convection. Hot air rises, and your monk is a living radiator at the bottom of a well. The air that he breathes out will create an upward current, which would probably supply him with air for even extreme depths. My only issue is that carbon dioxide is slightly heavier than air, and as you go further down, the diffusion won't be strong enough to prevent the CO2 from settling at the bottom of the hole. Also, at that kind of depth you have another problem:
5. **15000+ meters – Air pressure:** The deeper you go, the greater the gravitational compression of air. At a few thousand meters, it would be noticeably uncomfortable and hard to breathe. At around 24-25 kilometers down you would die very quickly from nitrogen narcosis, because the air would be 4 times more pressurized than on the surface. Given the chronic exposure he's getting, I think he wouldn't be able to survive much more than 15km down, no matter how much perri-air they sent him. Beyond this, it isn't really a well if you have a pressure vessel at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Sooner or later, no matter where his well is located, you're going to hit water -- the [water table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_table).  If his well is any deeper than that, he'll be swimming, and that's as deep as he can safely go.

Whether your community can dig a well deep enough to get to, for example, the aquifers under the Sahara is another matter!

As for air, there are always microfissures and pores and splits between rock layers. (Think caves & mines.) Air circulation shouldn't be much of an issue.

Though I suppose if the monk ever complained, the community could always send down buckets of Perri-air:

[image]

Comment: Hmm - You have contravened several of the conditions I gave. I could enforce them by saying that the well is lined with impermeable ceramic and that the water table is way, way down. Sending down buckets of air would contradict my stipulation of "no active ventilation"!

Comment: But the air is *canned*, so no "active" ventilation involved. Active ventillation is fans and air handling infrastructure.  Also, you didn't stipulate a hermetically sealed well, just one where no noxious gasses are leaking into it.

Comment: I did say *"solid impermeable rock."*. I meant that to indicate nothing can get through it. You say there is no air-handling structure but, unless they just throw the cans down on his head, they need to lower the cans and collect the empties. That is 'air-handling'. The cans would have to be pretty big. If they are the size of a coke-can they would be used up in one or two breaths.

Comment: Hm. I wouldn't call it air handling. That generally means special equipment -- fans and ductwork and so forth. Anyway, you're already allowing buckets full of fresh to be lowered and buckets of foul air to be transported along with the food & waste! I'm sure Perri-air pressurise their cans of fresh air.

Comment: Also, even though you say "impermeable rock", that has a number of meanings. I take it to mean impermeable to liquids. Water molecules are fairly large and since you don't want your monk to tread water all the time, liquid impermeability is a safe assumption. Gas impermeability is a thing, but I doubt you could find a large enough depth of rock that is truly 100% absolutely sealed against gas exchange. So gas exchange was not a safe assumption. Doesn't much matter as there's plenty of gas exchange going on up and down the air column in the well anyway.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK They can indeed throw the cans down. The person at the bottom can have a shield as one of the items lowered down to him previously to help protect against this. If we say that the well is deep enough that the contents at the bottom melt away into the mantle of the planet (essentially, become part of the lava), then we could say the air-cans fulfill a vital second role of being a platform to stand on and distance oneself from the lava. There could be a very thick layer (100m? kilometers?) of cans that slowly settles into the heat that needs to be continually added to. Dual purpose